# Atmosphere how we can broadcast simple text

Tags: atmosphere, atmosphere.js

Using Atmosphere in springboot need to send one simple text message to all connected clients(browser).I used broadcast for the same.but the issue I am facing single text message repeatly passing 'n' number of times.can anyone please guide with this issue

Comment: Please, add some code to your question, then we can help you to improve a solution

Comment: @message
Public String onMessage(String deal)
{
(AtmosphereResource event injected)
event.broadcaster().broadcast((deal).toString());
return deal;
}